# DataContext scope during binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, scope

I have a **View A** that has a **UserControl U** containing its own **UserControl UChild**.

When I set the DataContext of A, will UChild get the DataContext of A using direct binding to its grandparent's property i.e. **{ Binding PropertyFromA }** within UChild?

I am trying to achieve this but looks like grandchild in my case does not get the DataContext.

Edit:

Some code I use:

My binding happens inside the VM, where BookList is an ObservableCollection that gets filled with Books:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public bool FillBooksCtrlList()
    {
        List<Book> list = DBHelper.GetRecipes();
        if (list == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            BookList = new ObservableCollection<Book>(list);
            foreach (Book book in BookList)
            {
                BookCtrlList.Add(new BookCtrl { DataContext = book, Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 10, 0) });
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

> In short, I am creating an instance of **BookCtrl** inside **BookPanelCtrl**
>   that belongs to the **MainView**.

Maybe the way I bind is the problem?

Comment: A little code would be helpful but yes, you should be able to bind PropertyFromA to UChild.

Comment: Yes, please see my small addition.

Comment: Why are you creating controls dynamically? Why don't bind the BookList to a control (like a ListControl) in the View?

Comment: I am trying to bind to a list of controls, but the list needs to be populated somehow in first place, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this. In your ViewModel you have an `ObservableCollection` containing `Book`s:

```
public class SomeViewModel {
    private ObservableCOllection<Book> _books;
    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books 
    {
        get
        {
            return _books;
        }
        set
        {
            _books = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Books");
        }
    }
}

public bool FillBooksCtrlList()
{
    List<Book> list = DBHelper.GetRecipes();
    if (list == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(list);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, in your View you could have something like:

```
<UserControl DataContext="SomeViewModel">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

This way the `UserControl` is bound to the ViewModel, the `ListBox` is bound to your list of `Book`s and each item in the `ListBox` is bound to the `Title` property of a book (I'm guessing books have a title).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me figure out my problem. Thank you!